# should I specify size in int or double for SizedBox?

Tags: flutter

When specifying widget size in flutter should I use int or double? For example, should it be `SizedBox(width:8)`, or `SizedBox(width:8.0)`?

I tried looking into flutter docs, but could find anything about this, so instead I looked for examples: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout and https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html, but they seem to be inconsistent...

Comment: Eventually it will convert to floating point number on compiler side. You can pass the one you prefer. If you are passing just `8`, typing `.0` takes extra time and i won't prefer typing this.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to set `round` value, you don't need to use `double` but otherwise you need it.

Answer (score 1):

If you go inside the SizedBox you will see a Double waiting there. When you type 8, SizedBox treats it as 8.0 anyway.

Inside SizedBox it is

```
const SizedBox({ super.key, this.width, this.height, super.child });
const SizedBox.expand({ super.key, super.child })
    : width = double.infinity,
      height = double.infinity;
```